# Jade - script not being recognized

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, express, pug

I have this very simple jade document and I want to import the standard jQuery script:

```
extends layout

block content
    h1 #{title}

    ul#messages
    form#formAddUser(name="adduser",method="post",action="")
        input#m(type="text", name="message")
        button#btnSubmit(type="submit") submit

    script(src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js")
```

which is the extension of

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')

  body
    block content
```

The thing is that the script is not even recognized! I would rather have a 404 response, but not even that, nothing happens at all. What am I doing wrong?

Thanks very much

P.S: I'm using express.js

Controller code:

```
router.get("/chat",function(req,res){
    res.render("chat",{title:"Chat"});
});
```

Update:
I added a piece to the layout

```
doctype html
html
  head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type="text/javascript")
      alert("hello!")
  body
    block content
```

that simple alert, and it doesn't work either!

Comment: Your update is completely a different thing. Inline scripts require a dot after the `script`.

Comment: What do you expect to happen? You're merely including jQuery, which doesn't do anything just by including it.

Comment: Thanks for the tip on the inline script. To your second comment, if I try to put that simple alert in a local script and call it, it just sends a 404

Comment: I think I'm missing some fundamentals here. Shouldn't including the jquery successfuly send a 200 response?

Comment: "Shouldn't including the jquery successfuly send a 200 response?" What should send a 200 response to where? Do you see a 404 error for `//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.0/jquery.min.js` using Firebug or similar?

Comment: Something's really wrong about my app. I created a whole new project, and tested it and it was fine. I have no idea what was happening here. But no, that was no error being sent.

Answer (score 0):

Add a dot for literal parsing in jade. Ie.

```
doctype html
html
    head
    title= title
    link(rel='stylesheet', href='/stylesheets/style.css')
    script(type="text/javascript").
        alert("hello!")
        console.log('Notice the dot after the script tag.');
body
    block content
```

If you add a dot, anything *within* that block (so indented) will not be parsed. Like this:

```
ul
    li This is inlined text.
    li.
       But this one is on its' own line, without the But being turned into a tag.
    li
       div this is a div inside a li
    li.
       div this is not a div, simple text inside a li.

p For added bonus, you can also use a colon and the next thing is also a tag.
p like, opposite of the dot.
p: a(href="#") Clickme!
p a(href="#") I'm not clickable :(
```

Jade is cool, isn't it?

**EDIT:** Oops, just noticed that the alert('hello') is just an appendix to your orig question. Let me update the answer.

**EDIT 2:** Actually, can you show your rendered HTML (for the first example) so I can see what is actually rendered and what do you expect to be there?

Comment: I was used http://fiddlesalad.com/jade/ to parse template used by OP, maybe it's bugged